# Ruby script doesn't wait for input in command prompt

Tags: ruby, command-prompt

My ruby script doesn't seem to wait for my input. I'm trying to follow a script that encrypts your file from the first chapter of the book: wicked cool ruby, but it doesn't wait for my input after I run the file in command prompt.

Code snippet that is causing trouble:

```
require 'crypt/blowfish'

unless ARGV[0]
   puts "Usage: ruby encrypt.rb <filename.ext>"
   puts "Example: ruby encrypt.rb secret.stuff"
   exit
end

#take in the file name to encrypt as an argument
filename = ARGV[0].chomp
puts filename

c = "Encrypted_#{filename}"

if File.exists?(c)
   puts "File already exists."
   exit
end

print 'Enter your encryption key (1-56 bytes): '
kee = gets.chomp

begin
   blowfish = Crypt::Blowfish.new(kee)
   blowfish.encrypt_file(filename.to_str, c)
   puts 'Encryption SUCCESS!'
rescue Exception => e
   puts "An error occurred during encryption: \n #{e}"
end
```

What I see in cmd after I try to run the file:

```
C:\Users\me\>ruby new4.rb fileToEnrypt.txt
Enter your encryption key (1-56 bytes): An error occurred during encryption:
 can't convert String into Integer
C:\Users\me\>
```

Comment: It'll be great if you can provide more code.

Comment: Seems to work here, I don't see what the problem is..

Comment: Just provide all of the code.

Comment: It's not necessary to `chomp` this: `filename = ARGV[0].chomp`. ARGV elements don't have trailing new-lines... well, they *could* but you'd have to go out of your way to put them there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems here:

Concerning the fact that you don't get the user prompt, replace your code with:

```
kee = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Concerning the error message, it's because:

> The key is anywhere between 64 and 448 bits (8 and 56 bytes), and
>   should be passed as a packed string

Comment: This let me enter what I needed but I think Saurabh is correct in saying that gem is incompatible with 1.9.

Comment: Can you say why I need the $stdin.gets.chomp vs. merely the gets.chomp?

Comment: It seems that `gets` alone take the passed argument to script if any. If no argument, then it ask the user, whereas `$stdin.gets` always prompt the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to convert the string into an integer by using encryption.

`kee = gets.chomp` is returning a string according to the input you are giving, which is a string, and, when you encrypt a string into integer, the error will occur.

The error message itself says:

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

Also, the gem you are using apparently has not been updated to work with Ruby 
1.9.

The [source](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/203985) says that there may be other incompatibilities in the gem.

Comment: According to the question, the script isn't even allowing anything to be entered. Notice the error message. There is no new line after the `print` message and the `puts` in the `rescue` block. This means the user is not even getting the chance to enter anything.

Comment: this is incompatible with ruby 1.9.

Comment: Thanks ByScripts actually answered my question, but you provide good information, Thanks!